# Make a 'slow' test suite with clojure.test

Tags: testing, clojure

I want this test to run with every `lein test`:

```lisp
(ns acker.core-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [acker.core :refer :all]))

(deftest ackermann-test
  (testing "ack-1, ack-2, ack-3"
    (are [m n e]
         (= (ack-1 m n) (ack-2 m n) (ack-3 m n) e)
         0 0  1
         0 1  2
         0 2  3
         1 0  2
         1 1  3
         1 2  4
         2 0  3
         2 1  5
         2 2  7
         3 0  5
         3 1 13
         3 2 29)))
```

I want to make `ackermann-slow-test` only run when I ask for it:

```lisp
(deftest ackermann-slow-test
  (testing "ackermann (slow)"
    (are [m n e] (= (ack-3 m n) e)
         3 3     61
         3 4    125
         4 0     13
         4 1  65533)))
```

The full code is available on Github: https://github.com/bluemont/ackermann

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to [Making Leiningen work for You](http://p.hagelb.org/conj-2010-slides.org.html) by Phil Hagelberg, the `test-selectors` feature was added to [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) in version 1.4.

Two easy steps. First, add this to `project.clj`:

```lisp
:test-selectors {:default (complement :slow)
                 :slow :slow
                 :all (constantly true)}
```

Second, mark up your test with metadata:

```lisp
(deftest ^:slow ackermann-slow-test
  (testing "ackermann (slow)"
    (are [m n e] (= (ack-3 m n) e)
         3 3     61
         3 4    125
         4 0     13
         4 1  65533)))
```

Now you have three options for running your tests:

```sh
⚡ lein test
⚡ lein test :slow
⚡ lein test :all
```

Also, this information is easy to find with `lein test -h`:

> Run the project's tests.
>
> Marking deftest or ns forms with metadata allows you to pick selectors
>   to specify a subset of your test suite to run:
>
> ```
> (deftest ^:integration network-heavy-test
>   (is (= [1 2 3] (:numbers (network-operation)))))
> ```
>
> Write the selectors in project.clj:
>
> ```
> :test-selectors {:default (complement :integration)
>                  :integration :integration
>                  :all (constantly true)}
> ```
>
> Arguments to this task will be considered test selectors if they are
>   keywords, otherwise arguments must be test namespaces or files to run.
>   With no arguments the :default test selector is used if present,
>   otherwise all tests are run. Test selector arguments must come after
>   the list of namespaces.
>
> A default :only test-selector is available to run select tests. For
>   example, `lein test :only leiningen.test.test/test-default-selector`
>   only runs the specified test. A default :all test-selector is
>   available to run all tests.
>
> Arguments: ([& tests])